# Does the following sequence of functions converge uniformly to its pointwise limit?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, proof-verification

**Problem Statement**

> Given
>   $$f_n(z) = \frac{z+in}{2z^2 - 3nz}$$
>   defined on 
>   $$E = {B_1}^{*}(0) = \left\{z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 < \left|z\right| < 1\right\},$$
>   does the sequence $\{f_n\}$ converge uniformly to its pointwise limit?

**Attempt**

If $f_n \to f$ pointwise on $E$, the limit function is
$$f(z) := \lim_{n \to \infty}{f_n(z)} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\bigg(\frac{z+in}{2z^2 - 3nz}\bigg) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\bigg(\frac{\frac{z}{n}+i}{\frac{2z^2}{n} - 3z}\bigg) = \frac{0+i}{0-3z}=\frac{-i}{3z}.$$

Claim:  $f_n \not\to f$ uniformly on $E$.

Proof of Claim:  Consider
$$z_n = \frac{1}{n+1} \in E, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$$

$$f_n(z_n) = f_n\bigg(\frac{1}{n+1}\bigg)=\frac{\frac{1}{n+1}+in}{2\bigg(\frac{1}{n+1}\bigg)^2 - 3n\bigg(\frac{1}{n+1}\bigg)}=\frac{(n+1)+in(n+1)^2}{2-3n(n+1)}$$

$$\left|f_n(z_n) - f(z_n)\right| = \left|\frac{(n+1)+in(n+1)^2}{2-3n(n+1)}+i\cdot\frac{n+1}{3}\right| = \sqrt{\bigg(\left(\frac{n+1}{2-3n(n+1)}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2(n+1)}{3(2 - 3n(n+1)}\right)^2\bigg)}$$
$$=\frac{n+1}{\left|2 - 3n(n+1)\right|}\cdot\bigg(1 + \frac{4}{9}\bigg) \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty.$$

The same thing happens when assuming that
$$z_n = \frac{1}{n} \in E, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq 2.$$

**Query**

> Does this mean that the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ does converge uniformly to its pointwise limit $f$?  If so, how does one go about proving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$f_n(z) = \frac{z+in}{2z^2 - 3nz}=
\frac{3+2i}{3(2z-3n)}-\frac{i}{3z}.$$
Therefore, as $n$ goes to infinity, 
$$\sup_{0<|z|<1}\left|f_n(z)-\left(-\frac{i}{3z}\right)\right|
=\sup_{0<|z|<1}\frac{|3+2i|}{3|2z-3n|}
\leq 5/3\sup_{0<|z|<1}\frac{1}{|2z-3n|}\leq \frac{5/3}{3n-2}\to 0.$$
and sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ converges **uniformly** to $-\frac{i}{3z}$  in $E=\left\{z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 < \left|z\right| < 1\right\}$.